# Foreign key: on delete set null but only for one field of relation

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have two tables which are connected by relations on few columns. I wanna create foreign key that will take care of cleaning connected entities but not by deleting them - I need to use "SET NULL" option.

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE resource
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  project_id integer NOT NULL,
  lang character(2) NOT NULL,
  recource_id integer,
  reserved_by integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT resource_v0_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, project_id,  lang);

CREATE TABLE resource_list
(
  id integer NOT NULL
  project_id integer NOT NULL,
  lang character(2) NOT NULL,
  name character varying(128),
  CONSTRAINT resource_list_v0_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, project_id,  lang);
  );
```

How can I add following FK to set recource_id to BULL when resource is deleted. It should look something like that:

```
ALTER TABLE resource
ADD CONSTRAINT $2
  FOREIGN KEY (resource_id, project_id, lang)
  REFERENCES resource_list(id, project_id, lang)
  ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

What is important I want set NULL only to resource.recource_id not for all connected fields. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is resource.id unique?  If so add a unique constraint there, and a second foreign key that sets null.  Then add a second foreign key with an initially deferred check.